# My JUNIT tests is showing a java null pointer exception

Tags: java, junit

My class is as follows:

```
package Productions;

import java.util.Vector;

public class SetOfUsers extends Vector<User> {
    private static SetOfUsers register =  null;

    public SetOfUsers(){
        super();
    }

    public static SetOfUsers getInstance(){
        if (register == null) { 
            register = new SetOfUsers(); 
        }
        return register;    
    }

    public void addUser(User aUser){
        super.add(aUser);
    }

    public User findUserByName(String name){
       for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++){
           User user = elementAt(i); 
           if(user.getName().equals(name)){
               return user;
           }
       }
       return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my user class

```
package Productions;

public class User {
    private final String name;
    private final String password;
    private String projectName;
    private String type;


    public User(String name, String password,String type){
     this.name = name;
     this.password = password;
     this.type = type; //type of user

    }



    public boolean checkPassword(String pass)
    {
        if(password.equals(pass))
            return true;
             else
            return false;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public void allocateTask(){

    }
    public void removeTask(){

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Staff Name: " + this.getName() +
               ", Staff Pass: " + this.getPassword();
    }

}
```

Above is the class I am testing, it holds a `setOfUser` names

```
public void testFindUserByName() {
    String name = "Bob";
    SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();
    // User expResult = null;
    //User result = instance.findUserByName(name);
    //assertEquals(expResult, result);
    User result;
    instance.add(result);
    // User result = instance.findUserByName(name);

    //then
    assertEquals("Bob", result.getName());
}
```

When I run the test above I am getting a java null pointer exception, I don't understand this, it should pass since I am expecting the name `Bob`.

Comment: try to understand what exactly your class is meant to designed!

Answer (score 3):

You aren't adding the user before trying to find it so the result object is null.

EDIT:

Since the question changed since I answered, VD's answer below is correct - use that.

Comment: how shall I add user? and where?

Comment: @user3253321 looks like you don't understand what you are doing, may be you should study your `SetOfUser` a little before trying to add tests

Answer (score 1):

```
//following will create a user
User user = new User("UserName1","password","type");

//following will add a user in setOf users
SetOfUsers instance = new SetOfUsers();
instance.add(user);

//so now you have a set of users having a user with name as "UserName1" now do following

User result = instance.findUserByName("UserName1");
assertEquals("UserName1", result.getName());
```

this should work

Comment: I don't have a setName method in my user class

Comment: edited the ans, please go through basics of Java First.